# Laravel 5.2 strange character in the en of a value from a form

Tags: php, forms, laravel

I try to pass some value fro a form to a controller with Laravel 5.2. 
When I die the different fiels of my request,I can see a strange "1" in the end of my password value.

This is my form code :

```html
<form class="form-horizontal" action="{{ route('espace-client.login') }}" method="post">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="email" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Mail</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Adresse mail">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="password" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Mot de passe</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Mot de passe">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Connexion</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <input type="hidden" value="{{ Session::token() }}" name="_token">
</form>
```

And the excuted function into my controller :

```html
public function postLogin(Request $request)
 {
  die(print_r($request['email']." ".$request['password']));
  $this->validate($request, [
    'email' => 'required|email',
    'password' => 'required'
   ]
  );

  if(Auth::attempt(['email' => $request['email'], 'password' => $request['password']])) {
   return redirect()->route('espace-client');
  }
  return redirect()->route('inscription-client');
 }
```

I subimit *test@test.fr* and *1234*
**die** function return :

> test@test.fr 12341

and:

```html
array:3 [▼
  "email" => "test@test.fr"
  "password" => "1234"
  "_token" => "7p6gasKn5QuoZrEOos40eJwQzglikXcF0O6ZOzfz"
]
```

Do you an idea where is this "1" came from ?
Thank for help. :D

Comment: Can you also post the `dd($request->all())` output?

Comment: Can you post `dd($request->all())` this exact values? Try to output this: `dd($request->input('password'))`

Comment: Yep, sorry! It's done now

Answer (score 2):

Add a `true` to the `print_r` like below:

```
die(print_r($request['first_name']." ".$request['last_name'], true));
```

if you `echo print_r($foo)` you will print the contents of foo, followed by a string representation of the return value (which is 1). To avoid this, add a return value as `true`.

Btw, the best method is to use `$request->input('password');` instead of `$request['password']`